# Configuring static routing on three routers with IPv6 and IPv4

Tags: networking, router, routing, ipv6

I have my home network configured as shown on the diagram below. What I need is to be able to acces the NAS from the other subnet.

[image: Network diagram]

Two routers are running Asus WRT and static routing can be added
The modem/router is a standard ISP supplied cable modem with limited configuration options.

So, on the router A I have added a static route:

```
Host IP:192.168.2.1
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.1
Metric: 2
Interface: LAN
```

On the router B:

```
Host IP: 192.168.1.15
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.1
Metric: 2
Interface: LAN
```

On the modem there is only an option to filter ports and IPs (is it the same as static routes above?) and it only allows IPv6 addresses in this place. So I have put these entries:

```
- Outbound:
source: 2a02:a319:8242:8c00:0:ffff:c0a8:196 / 128
destination: ::ffff:192.168.0.2 / 128
Allow
```

```
- Outbound:
source: 2a02:a319:8242:8c00:0:ffff:c0a8:201 / 100
destination: ::ffff:192.168.0.3 / 128
Allow
```

I have translated IPv4 to IPv6 addresses using an online tool, not sure if I used it correctly?

As you might have guessed my setup is not working (NAS can't be reached from outside of its subnet). Any advice what am I doing wrong?

Also, how can I debug such a config?

Comment: You are missing routes between the two subnets and will have to do that on the modem, which you say has limited configuration. But why are you bothering with such a complex setup for such a small network? I suggest to simplify by putting everything in the subnet of `192.168.0.X`, make routers A & B into simple extenders, leaving the modem as the DHCP master (or even setting everything to static IPs).

Comment: Unfortunately I need such a complexity: one router is "normal", the other is connected to a VPN. So now the question is if I will be able to set up routing on the modem? 

I guess, what I have done is not what I should have done?

Comment: Does the VPN allow split routing?

Comment: I guess so. I ended up with chaining those routers, as it seems the modem doesn't have all the configuration options I needed to do the intended setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the gateway for **Router A** should be

```
Host IP:192.168.2.0  # that's the network address
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.2  # Router B knows how to handle that subnetwork
Metric: 2
Interface: LAN
```

Router B

```
Host IP: 192.168.1.15
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.2   # Router A will know how to handle the packets going to that host
Metric: 2
Interface: LAN
```

Nope, what you're seeing is the [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

I think the conf you posted to open the port is wrong, but I don't know that ASUS model.

I think it should be:

The modem has the conf as router B (so that it will be able to forward the packet):

```
Host IP: 192.168.1.15
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.2   # Router A will know how to handle the packets going to that host
Metric: 2
Interface: LAN
```

From the outside you choose the port forwarding sayig: *I'm pointing to the router at **port X**, then forward this packets at **192.168.1.15:NasPort*** with NasPort the port where you connect to the NAS. (HTTP is 80, HTTPS is 443)

Comment: You answer helped me a lot, however since the modem/router lacks the configuration options I ended up with chaining routers: `modem -> router B -> router A` and from there it was an easy job to set everything up correctly.